# Why Ip address of cloud service is changed after update deployment from portal

Tags: azure, deployment, service, ip, cloud

I have update the deployment by uploading new package in the azure management portal. But by using this Ip address of cloud service is change. How It could? As I havn't deleted old deployment I had just choose the option "Update Production Deployment" in azure management portal . Anyone have any solution please?

Comment: So you did an in-place update of the production deployment? Multiple instances? Did the structure of the service change in any way (e.g. more/less roles, ports, csdef)

Comment: I have update the deployment of production

Comment: But I hadn't deleted old one I just choosed the "Update Production Deployment" in azure management portal

Comment: "The VIP doesn’t change unless you delete the deployment explicitly **or it is implicitly deleted by the deployment update process**" see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj614593.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the size (not number of instances) of any virtual machine since the previous deployment? That would be a reason for the virtual IP to change.